# How to represent logical expression with brackets as an object?

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to represent logical expression with AND, OR and brackets as an object structure in Java. The main criteria are to make it as simple as possible and use only Java 8.

Here's what I came to. The main problem is the `brackets`. How to build the structure that can represent the following expression `((A and B) or (C or(D and (E or F and G) and H))`. The main problem is that expression in brackets would be an Array/Collection but also a single object.

```
class Expression extends Operand {

    private Operand operand;
    private Operator operator;

    Expression(Operand operand, Operator operator) {
        this.operand = operand;
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    static class Condition extends Operand {
        private String type;
        private Object value;

        public Condition(String type, Object value) {
            this.type = type;
            this.value = value;
        }

    }

    enum Operator {
        AND, OR, NULL;
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas on how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Imagine your expression as a list of expressions. Expression is now a single object containing zero, one or multiple expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your structure recursive:

```
class Expression extends Operand {

    private Operand operand;
    private Operator operator;

    //if true, this.operand and this.operator are irrelevant
    private boolean aggregated = false; 

    private List<Expression> aggregatedExpressions;

    //if AND applies to aggregatedExpressions, else OR
    private boolean and = true; 

    ....
 }
```

I'm assuming that `operand` and `operator` make up your actual expression to be evaluated.

An expression that can hold other expressions with a logical operator to define how they're composed (I used *aggregated* in the code) will allow you to have "expressions" at arbitrary depths.

Comment: Since the question seems to be related to a school homework, I would recommend defining a more elaborate OOP approach, even though this is correct

Answer (score 2):

You should encapsulate the internal structure of each expression and subexpression.

Usually it looks something like:

```
interface Expression {
    Result evaluate(EvaluationContext ctx);
    void traverse(ExpressionVisitor visitor);
}

class Constant implements Expression {
    Result value;
    Result evaluate(EvaluationContext ctx) {
        return value;
    }
    ...
}
class AndExpression implements Expression {
    private List<Expression> operands;
    ....
}
```

etc...

The `EvaluationContext` would store the values of variables and other run-time information.  It's where a `VariableExpression` like `A` would look up the value of the variable "A".